# How image path works?

Tags: css

I see this when inspecting the site

```css
background: url("http://nepotech.com/thelandmark//images/stories/bg/rooms.jpg")
```

the double slash after **thelandmark**. when you delete one of the slashes it doesn't work. But how is this working?

[Live demo](http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/rooms) inspect the background image

Comment: However I noticed removing one slash is also working but slow when removed.. but how // worked?

Comment: It is single. In which browser you get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "version" after the url like:

```
http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/images/stories/bg/rooms.jpg?v=1
```

If I type http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/images/stories/bg/rooms into the address bar the image shows up. Maybe its caching?

Answer (score 0):

it seem that is an error from developer somewhere in the code, this question is already answered [Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls)